# In cmake how can I install shared library from subdirectory?

Tags: c++, cmake

for example, if I have a project like this:

```
trunk
   |_ CMakeLists.txt
   |_ src
   |   |_ CMakeLists.txt
   |   |_ componentA
   |   |_ componentB
   | 
   |_ test
       |_ unit
```

Is it possible to install libComponentA and libComponentB from trunk/CMakeLists.txt or trunk/src/CMakeLists.txt? I tried but it complains 
my target

> does not exist in this directory

after some googling it seems cmake install(TARGET ...) command only searches current directory, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a command like `install ( TARGETS <libs> DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/<dir> )` in `trunk/src/CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can give full path to the `install` command. You can use cmake variables like this `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/` (trunk directory) and `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/` (location of the current CMakeLists.txt file) to ease  your work.